# C# - CSOM - Upload a file to a subdirectory in Sharepoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, upload, csom

I'm trying to upload a file to SharePoint Online and I got this sample code:

```
var uploadFile = list
            .RootFolder
            .Folders
            .GetByPath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl("A"))
            .Files
            .Add(newFile);

ctx.Load(uploadFile);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Which works perfectly fine, so everything around it works. But apparently this snippet

```
var uploadFile = list
            .RootFolder
            .Folders
            .GetByPath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl("A/B"))
            .Files
            .Add(newFile);

ctx.Load(uploadFile);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Throws System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException even though both directories exist. So how can I upload a file to the subdirectory "B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upload file like this:

```
 public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context,string uploadFolderUrl, string uploadFilePath)
{
    var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation
    {
            Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath),
            Overwrite = true,
            Url = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath)
    };
    var targetFolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uploadFolderUrl);
    var uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
    context.Load(uploadFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}

using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     ctx.Credentials = credentials;

     UploadFile(ctx,"LibName/FolderName/Sub Folder Name/Sub Sub Folder Name/Sub Sub Sub Folder Name",filePath);   
}
```

Please check out another similiar thread here:

[Alternative Save/OpenBinaryDirect methods for CSOM for SharePoint Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918952/alternative-save-openbinarydirect-methods-for-csom-for-sharepoint-online/62930801#62930801)

Comment: I should have mentioned that we're using .NET core and .SaveBinaryDirect() isn't available. But we scrapped the Plan already as it took too much time.

Comment: @realemx, for .NET Core solution, I have updated the code in my answer, please check